# Java Thread stop notifier

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

My task here is to perform unzip operation using multiple threads. I did it with following structure Way.

```
// A class for Unzipping files
public class UnzipClass extends Thread(){
    private String zipfile;
    private Thread t;
    public UnzipClass(String zipFile){
       this.zipFile = zipFile;
    }

    public String getZipFile() {
       return zipFile;
    }

    public void setZipFile(String zipFile) {
       this.zipFile = zipFile;
    }

    public void run() {
    try {
        unzipFolder(this.getZipFile());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Unzipper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
public void start(String filename){
    if (t == null){
        t = new Thread(this,filename);
        t.start();
    }
}
public unzipFolder(String zipFile) throws ZipException, IOException   
    // Here is the Unzip Method 
 }

}

// Now I am calling this class from another class
public static void main(){
   Thread t1 = new UnzipClass("filename1");  
   t1.start();
    if(!(t1.isAlive())){
      logEvent("Unzip Complete");
    } 

  // Similarly I have Thread t2 with another file name 

 }
```

The **above code works perfect** and unzips the files but I have following problems.

1. I wanted to use *implements Runnable* , but I cannot use it because I did not find a way to pass variable(Filename) to another class which implements Runnable  and do it. Literally: How to implement Runnable instead of extends Thread`
2. Using above method, How can I detect if the unzip process has been completed. To be specific how to stop the thread when the file unzip process is completed`.

Any sort of hint or solution would be really great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.change

```
public class UnzipClass extends Thread
```

into

```
public class UnzipClass implements Runnable
```

and use

```
Runnable t1 = new UnzipClass("filename1");
```

to create the thread.

2.
use a while loop here

```
while((t1.isAlive())){
  logEvent("Unziping...");
} 

logEvent("Unzip Complete");
```

but using a flag like `boolean isComplete` in the `UnzipClass` will me more effective. like

in class `UnzipClass` add

```
private boolean complete=false;
```

then,

```
public void run() {
try {
    unzipFolder(this.getZipFile());
    complete=true;
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Unzipper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}

//simple getter.
public boolean isComplete()
{
    return this.complete;
}
```

in main...

```
while(!t1.isComplete()){
  logEvent("Unziping...");
} 

logEvent("Unzip Complete");
```

Comment: `but using a flag like boolean isComplete in the UnzipClass will me more effective and then` can you please illustrate it with an example.

Comment: It is better to use a blocking call like `t1.join` than looping around testing if the thread is still alive.

Comment: @Nepal12 example given

Comment: @NeilMasson agreed. but this is easy to understand

Comment: @NeilMasson: Your hint actually helps me :D , Since my threads  dont need much time, so join() seems to be a good option for this, However I'll try using Executors and ExecutorsService as suggested by Antoniossss.

Answer (score 2):

Just change `extends Thread` to `implements Runnable`.

While creating new thread, you will do

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new UnzipClass("filename1"));
```

Instead of

```
Thread t1 = new UnzipClass("filename1");
```

As you want to unzip couple files simultaniously, try using `ExecutorService` for that. You can `submit` `Runnable` taks to be executed by thread pool - this way, you will reuse already existing threads.
Check [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) and [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please, check this solution.

It uses Java 8 features, but it can be easily upgraded to be used with Java 5 / 6 / 7 (and external library, like Apache Commons or Guava).

```
/**
 * File unzipping service
 */
public class Unzipper {

    /**
     * Default number of threads
     */
    private static byte DEFAULT_THREADS_COUNT = 5;

    /**
     * Completion handler
     */
    private Consumer onComplete;

    /**
     * Unzipping tasks
     */
    private Collection<File> unzippingTasks = new LinkedList<>();

    /**
     * Add task for unzipping file
     *
     * @param file Path to file to be unzipped
     * @return upgraded <code>this</code> instance
     */ 
    public Unzipper unzip(String file) {

        //check validity of 'file' string: non-null and non-empty
        //check that file pointed by 'file' exists

        unzippingTasks.add(new File(file));
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Add unzipping completion handler
     * 
     * @param onComplete Unzipping completion handler
     * @return upgraded <code>this</code> instance
     */
    public Unzipper onComplete(Consumer onComplete) {

        //check validity of 'onComplete' object: non-null
        this.onComplete = onComplete;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Run files unzipping (with default number of threads)
     */
    public void run() {
        run(DEFAULT_THREADS_COUNT);
    }

    /**
     * Run files unzipping
     *
     * @param threads Number of parallel threads
     */
    public void run(byte threads) {

        //check validity of 'threads' argument: non-negative and non-zero

        //check that we have at least one 'unzipping' task
        if(unzippingTasks.isEmpty()) {

            //output to log that unzipping tasks list is empty
            return;
        }

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(threads);
        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads + 1); //we are not blocking in 'run' method, so we should create extra thread to wait for all tasks completion

        for(File file: unzippingTasks) {

            executor.execute(() -> {
                //unzip file
                latch.release();
            });
        }

        executor.execute(() -> {

            latch.await(); //wait for all unzipping tasks completion
            if(onComplete) //you can use 'optional' here instead
                onComplete.accept(null);
        });

        executor.shutdown();
    }
}

....

//Usage example
new Unzipper()
    .unzip("<path-to-some-file>")
    .unzip("<path-to-another-file>")
    .unzip("<path-to-some-another-file>")
    .onComplete(() -> {
        //make you log output
    })
    .run();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.zip.ZipException;

public class UnzipClass {
    // Now I am calling this class from another class
    public static void main() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new UnzipClassRunner("filename1"));
        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

class UnzipClassRunner implements Runnable {
    private String zipfile;


    public UnzipClassRunner(String zipFile) {
        this.zipfile = zipFile;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            unzipFolder(zipfile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Unzipper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                    ex);
        }
    }

    public void unzipFolder(String zipFile) throws ZipException, IOException {
        //
    }
}
```